# How to add onPress in react navigation tabBarButton

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a problem on adding onPress in `tabBarButton` using `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs`

Actual output: Whenever I click to the button, it redirects me to the component although the user is not admin or allowed to view

Here is my code:

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="AdminDashboard"
   component={AdminDashboard}
   options={{
    title: "",
    tabBarLabel: "Admin Dashboard",
    tabBarButton: (props) =>
      !userAuthorized ? (
         <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => setPromptVisible(true)} // This is to trigger the prompt if user is not allowed to view admin dashboard
          {...props}
         />
       ) : (
          <TouchableOpacity {...props} />
       ),
                  
   }}
/>
```

Expected output: if the user is not admin or not allowed, overlay prompt should appear instead of redirecting to `AdminDashboard` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like below

```
tabBarButton: (props) => (
  <TouchableOpacity
    {...props}
    onPress={() => {
      if (!userAuthorized) {
        setPromptVisible(true);
      } else {
        props.onPress();
      }
    }}
  />
),
```

Basically the onPress in the props would do the redirection, you can call it based on your condition or call your own function. Make sure that userAuthorized is in your component.